# Insert Sequence into Database, Slick 3

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I want to add a method to my DAOs to allow me to insert a list of elements rather than a single element, for the single element I have:

```
def add(userGroup: UserGroup): Future[Int] = {
  dbConfig.db.run(userGroups += userGroup)
}
```

The documentation seems to suggest I should be able to use ++= like so

```
def add(userGroups: Seq[UserGroup]): Future[Int] = {
  dbConfig.db.run(userGroups ++= userGroups)
}
```

http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#inserting

But this doesn't work, the ++= isn't what it expects apparently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++=` added a sequence to `TableQuery`. From your second snippet, it looks like you are just adding `userGroups: Seq[UserGroup]` to itself rather than `TableQuery` instance.

If your first snippet works, adding `userGroups: Seq[UserGroup]` to `this.userGroups` could work.

```
def add(userGroups: Seq[UserGroup]): Future[Int] = {
  dbConfig.db.run(this.userGroups ++= userGroups)
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! Just a silly naming issue, I think I need a break

Answer (score 0):

For everybody landing on this question now (with Slick 3.2 and higher): The return type is not `Future[Int]` but `Future[Option[Int]]`. Reason for this is that not all databases actually return a number of inserted row. The documentation describes it [here](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/queries.html#inserting).

So the code in newer versions of Slick must look like this:

```
def add(userGroups: Seq[UserGroup]): Future[Option[Int]] = {
  dbConfig.db.run(this.userGroups ++= userGroups)
}
```